# Read content of file line by line in unix using 'line'

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file - abc, which has the below content -

```
Bob 23  
Jack 44  
Rahul 36
```

I also have a shell script that do the addition of all the numbers here.
The specific line that picks up these numbers is -

```
while read line  
do  
    num=echo ${line#* }  
    sum=`expr $sum + $num`  
    count=`expr $count + 1`  
done< "$readfile"
```

I assumed that the code is just picking up the last field from file, but it's not. If i modify the file like

```
Bob 23 12  
Jack 44 23  
Rahul 36 34
```

The same script fails with syntax error.

NOTE: I know there are other ways to pick up the field value, but i would like to know how this works.

Comment: Can you show us the whole script? You want the sum of numbers in last column alone?

Comment: the read part is as below -  while read line  do  num=`echo ${line#* }`  sum=`expr $sum + $num`  count=`expr $count + 1`  done < "$readfile"

Comment: Please update the code as part of the question and not in comments

Comment: Are you trying the sum up the value in the last column?

Comment: Yes, the program sums up the value in last column. I am not able to understand how does it work. As i mentioned i tried adding one more field in all three lines, but it failed with syntax error.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion `${line#* }` removes characters up to the *first* space, not the last.

Comment: Your fundamental syntax error is `num=echo ${line#* }` which sets the variable `num` to the string value `echo` and then attempts to execute the command `${line#* }` in this environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `${line#* }` will skip the shortest string from the beginning till it finds a space and returns the rest. It worked fine when you had just 2 columns. But the same will *not* work when 3 columns are present as it will return you the last 2 column values which when you use it in the sum operator will throw you an error. To explain that, just imagine

```
str='foo bar'
printf '%s\n' "${str#* }"
bar
```

but imagine the same for 3 fields

```
str='foo bar foobar'
printf '%s\n' "${str#* }"
bar foobar
```

To fix that use the parameter expansion syntax of `"${str##* }"` to skip the longest sub-string from beginning. To fix your script for the example with 3 columns, I would use a script as below.

This does a simple input redirection on the file and uses the `read` command with the default `IFS` value which is a single white space. So I'm getting only the 3rd field on each line (even if it has multiple fields), the `_` mark the fields I'm skipping. You could also have some variables as place-holders and use their value in the scripts also.

```
declare -i sum

while read -r _ _ value _ ; do
    ((sum+=value)
done < file

printf '%d\n' "$sum"
```

See [Bash - Parameter Expansion (Substring removal)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to understand more.

You could also use the PE syntax `${line##* }` as below,

```sh
while read -r line ; do
    ((sum+=${line##* }))
done < file
```

---

[Not relevant to the current question]

If you just want the sum to be computed and not specifically worried about using `bash` script for this. You can use a simple `Awk` command to sum up values in 3rd column as

```
awk '{sum+=$3}END{print sum}' inputfile
```

Comment: That was cool. Does the count of '#' indicate how many spaces to skip ?

Comment: @Justin No. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion (search for `parameter#word`).

Comment: @Justin: Follow the link I shared